# Formula that references a different sheet each row based on set criteria?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm wondering if someone can help me. I have a Google sheets workbook with more than 50 individual sheets. This workbook has a primary 'index' page that collates set data fields from each sheet. I'm currently expanding this but the formula I am using requires me to change the referencing sheet per row so the data is pulled for the correct sheet. My questions is, is there a way to automate this process as it is incredibly time consuming?

As an example -

Column A is Product -

- T-shirts
- Shirts
- Jeans
- Trousers
- Shoes
- Boots
- Etc.

Each of these products in row A has a separate referencing sheet.

Column B - Damaged on delivery

Column C - Damage on transit

Column B & C are referencing data from each sheet and producing that data on the index page against the correct product.

I would like a formula that references each individual sheet based on the sheet name and the name on the index page.

Hope this is enough information. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, welcome to WebApps. I can't explain why there has been no response to your question; but we'd certainly like to help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a combination of `ADDRESS` and `INDIRECT`?

`ADDRESS` has the advantage of being able to optionally include the sheet name. And since each item in Column A is the name of the respective sheet, this makes it very easy to build the address.

The formula in Cell B2: is:
`=indirect(address(7,2,4,true,A2))`

---

**SAMPLE- Index page**

[image: index]

---

**SAMPLE - T-Shirts page**

[image: tshirts]